# React: apply multiple filters to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I'm starting with react and I have an array of objects called arrayToFilter I want to apply multiple filters to, ideally when a user changes the filter select options all filters should be applied to the array and the results returned into a filteredResults array to show, I already have each filter function and their constants but I don't know how to apply all the filters one after another...

Here is my code:

```
    const [ arrayToFilter, setArrayToFilter ] = useState([ /*array of objects to apply filters to*/ ]);
    const [ filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([ /*array of filtered objects*/ ]);
    const [ categoryOptions, setCategoryOptions ] = useState([ 1,2,3 ]);
    const [ selectedCategoryOptions, setSelectedCategoryOptions ] = useState([ ]);
    const [ searchName, setSearchName ] = useState('');
    const [ hideVenuesWithoutDiscounts, setHideVenuesWithoutDiscounts ] = useState(true);

    const filterHideVenuesWithoutDiscounts = () => 
    {
        if(hideVenuesWithoutDiscounts)
        {
            return arrayToFilter.filter(item => item.discounts.length > 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return arrayToFilter;
        }   
    };

    const filterSelectedCategoryOptions = () => 
    {
        return arrayToFilter.filter(item => item.category_id.includes(selectedCategoryOptions));
    };

    const filtersearchName = () => 
    {
        return arrayToFilter.filter(item =>  item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) != -1);
    };

    useEffect(() => 
    {
        //Filter options updated so apply all filters here
    },
    [searchName, hideVenuesWithoutDiscounts, selectedCategoryOptions]);
```

Notice useEffect, afaik this is like watch property in vue, I'd like to fire all the filters when a filter input changes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's simple, you can pass the filtered array as a parameter to the filtering functions so that they can filter the filtered array.

For example:

```js
const filterHideVenuesWithoutDiscounts = (array) => {
    if (hideVenuesWithoutDiscounts) {
        return array.filter((item) => item.discounts.length > 0);
    } else {
        return array;
    }
};

const filterSelectedCategoryOptions = (array) => {
    return array.filter((item) => item.category_id.includes(selectedCategoryOptions));
};

const filtersearchName = (array) => {
    return array.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) != -1);
};

useEffect(() => {
    //Filter options updated so apply all filters here
    let result = arrayToFilter;
    result = filterHideVenuesWithoutDiscounts(result);
    result = filterSelectedCategoryOptions(result);
    result = filtersearchName(result);
    setArrayToFilter(result);
}, [searchName, hideVenuesWithoutDiscounts, selectedCategoryOptions]);
```

Comment: This was the easiest and really understandable answer even for someone like me who is very naive to JavaScript and React. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could chain multiple filters together in the array.

```
arrayToFilter
.filter(item => item.category_id.includes(selectedCategoryOptions))
.filter(item => item.discounts.length > 0)
.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) != -1)
```

Comment: did you mean to include the semicolon on the second line?

Comment: That's a typo. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest one more approach, using `Array.reduce`, as chaining `Array.filters` will go over whole array every time that way which can be resource expensive if arrays are huge.

Example:

```
const filterMethods = [
  (item => item.category_id.includes(selectedCategoryOptions)),
  (item => item.discounts.length > 0),
  ((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) != -1)
]

const filteredArray = arrayToFilter.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < filterMethods.length; i++) {
    if (!filterMethods[i](currentItem)) {
      return accumulator
    }
  }
  return [...accumulator, currentItem]
}, [])
```

EDIT:
After sleeping a while, I noticed that you can actually use `Array.filter` in similar way as reduce, without going multiple times over the array.

```
const filterMethods = [
  (item => item.category_id.includes(selectedCategoryOptions)),
  (item => item.discounts.length > 0),
  ((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) != -1)
]

const filteredArray = arrayToFilter.filter((item) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < filterMethods.length; i++) {
    if (!filterMethods[i](item)) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
})
```

Comment: I've noticed that you could actually probably use `Array.filter` in similar way, look the edit, I think that would work too in your situation.